# Austrocylindropuntia subulata breaking off

Tags: succulents, cactus

I've had this one for about 3-4 years - found a piece of if on the ground broken off from the big plant and potted it, and it kept growing since (in the same pot all this time). Few days ago, one of the branches just snapped off from the base, and now it seems like another one is slouching and will snap off too. It's a bit yellow down at the base. Otherwise it looks very healthy, and other branches look fine too.

I think here isn't enough light for them where I live, but it kept growing all this time so I have no idea what the problem is.

Broken branch:
[image: Broken off branch]

Weak branch which I'm afraid will snap off if I remove the improvised support:
[image: Slouching branch]

Base of the weak branch (1) and of the broken branch (2):
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct; there is not enough light to support robust growth for this plant. In order to stop the etiolated growth and pieces falling off you'll have to give it the appropriate amount of light.

If that's not possible, don't worry about it, it will continue to grow and pieces will fall off occasionally. As long as you like it, it's OK.

Comment: Thank you! Should I try replanting the broken branches? If it's possible, is there anything special I should do, or just leave them to dry for a few days and then stick into a well-draining soil?

Comment: Yes, they should root easily. Where it's native, they break branches off and plant them in a line to make a fence. Don't water them much when you are rooting them. Put them in a warm-ish place with some sun (not too much).

Comment: Thank you a lot!